# How can I automatically test or check that the attributes used in __str__ exist in the class of my Django model?

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-models

In a Django 2.2 project, I renamed an attribute in a django.db.models.Model class. This attribute was used in `__str__` but I forgot to rename it in the `__str__` method of this class. I discovered this bug quite late, when testing something about this class in a Django shell.
Is there a code testing app/framework/suite that could look for this kind of bug automatically? If not, how would a test checking that all attibutes used in `__str__` actually exist in the class look like?

Comment: You can check it from the admin panel. If any attributes missing then it show error

Comment: I had updated my admin.py file correctly to reflect the change of the attribute's name. I checked the class involved in the admin panel but I didn't notice any error message. The list and the individual objects were displayed normally. My question is about a test or an app that I could run programmatically to avoid a similar bug in the future... The error appeared in the shell when I issued: `MyModel.objects.all()` which uses the `__str__` method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have the Django test framework for this, I think the best answer to this is that you would write a test/tests for this.

An example of a unit test for a specific model would look like:

```
# my_app/tests.py
def test_my_model_str():
    my_model = MyModel.objects.create(...)

    try:
        my_model_str = my_model.__str__()
    except AttributeError as exc:
        self.fail("MyModel.__str__() raised an attribute error: %s" % str(exc)
```

If you wanted to test every model then it gets a bit more complicated, you can retrieve all the models in an app with the following code:

```
from django.apps import apps
print(apps.all_models["my_app"])
# OrderedDict([
#    ('model1', my_app.models.Model1),
#    ('model2', my_app.models.Model2)
# ])
```

Notice that we are given the model names (`model1`) and the model classes (`my_app.models.Model1`), we'll use this in the code below.

You would also need to create an object for all these models. There is a python package called [Factory Boy](https://github.com/FactoryBoy/factory_boy) that can be used to define factories to generate test models, but I'm not going to use this here, it's just worth knowing.

The final result might look something like the following test function:

```
# my_app/tests.py
from django.apps import apps
from my_app.models import Model1, Model2

def test_my_app_model_str_methods():
    my_models = apps.all_models["my_app"]
    my_model_instances = {
        "model1": Model1.objects.create(...),  # Model1Factory() if you use factory boy
        "model2": Model2.objects.create(...)
    }
    for model_key, model in my_models.items():
        try:
            model_obj = my_model_instances[model_key]
        except KeyError as exc:
            raise AssertionError("No model instance has been registered for %s" % model.__name__)

        try:
            model_obj.__str__()
        except AttributeError as exc:
            raise AssertionError("%s.__str__() raised an attribute error: %s" % (model_obj.__class__.__name__, str(exc))
```

This would execute the `__str__()` method on all the models, and if you have missed the test data for a model in your app then it will also raise an error.

To run it you can use the regular django test runner:

`python manage.py test`